# Ошибка "Null check operator used on a null value" при сохранении формы

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Заполняю форму текстом и пытаюсь его отправить на вторую страницу. При выполнении `form!.save();` вылетает ошибка *"Null check operator used on a null value"*, помоите решить проблему:

Первая страница
**form_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_form_example/models/model_user.dart';
import 'package:test_form_example/pages/profile.dart';

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FormPageState createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  User modelUser = User();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Form(
          child: ListView(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            onSaved: (value) => modelUser.name = value!,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: _formSave, child: Text('Отправить'))
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  void _formSave() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    form!.save();
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Profile(userInfo: modelUser)));
  }
}
```

Вторая страница
**profile.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_form_example/models/model_user.dart';

class Profile extends StatelessWidget {

  final User userInfo;
  Profile({required this.userInfo});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Name: ${userInfo.name}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Модель
**model_user.dart**

```
class User{
  late String name;
}
```

**Ошибка**:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _FormPageState._formSave (package:test_form_example/pages/form_page.dart:34:9)
#1      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
#2      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#3      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#4      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
#6      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
#7      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:444:20)
#8      GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:22)
#9      RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:278:11)
#10     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#11     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#12     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#13     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:185:10)
#18     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
#19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:98:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#c21f5
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: ready
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(128.0, 142.6)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(128.0, 8.6)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разберём такой маленький кусочек кода, который на первый взгляд не может сломаться.

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final form = _formKey.currentState;
form!.save();
```

Но точно не может сломаться? Давайте добавим детали чтобы разобраться:

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final FormState? form = _formKey.currentState;
form!.save();
```

Ага, теперь мы видим что `form` это `FormState?` т.е. может быть как `FormState`, так и `Null`.

Смотрим дальше и видим `form!.` (если конкретнее `!`) это `bang operator` он означает, что мы **игнорируем анализатор кода и точно уверены что в переменной не будет `null`**. Если это не так, то во время выполнения программы мы поймаем ошибку `Null check operator used on a null value` что означает что мы **пытаемся использовать у переменной значение которое равно null** какой-то метод.

Что-же нужно сделать, чтобы исправить данную проблему? Естественно проверить переменную на null:

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final FormState? form = _formKey.currentState;
if(form != null) {
  form!.save();
}
```

Или краткая запись:

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final FormState? form = _formKey.currentState;
form?.save();
```

Подытожим, использовать `bang operator` (`!`) крайне опасное дело, особенно в руках новичка. *И давайте не будем забывать, что Null Safety появился чтобы избавиться от ошибки на миллион.*

---

И на подлесок, у вас `form` равен `null` из-за того что вы не присвоили `_formKey` никакому виджету...

Comment: спасибо большое) действительно еще и забыл добавить key в виджет Form